Diamagnetic materials can become superconducting at lower temperature is the reverse possible?
We Know that when diamagnetic materials when cooled up ultimately becomes superconducting via the meissener effect, also we know that the superconducting materials lose their property when they cross their critical temperature. After this do they lose their diamagnetic property or does it persists after they reach it.

Welcome to Physics SE. Have you tried a search on the web for an answer before coming here?

@controlgroup  Yes I have tried searching in the web, but I got the results only for reducing the temperature i.e one way down. But there isn't a clear explanation for the heating up thing. Also main query was, whether the diamagnetic property gets lost entirely or some remain in the process of heating it back up while the superconductivity is lost; and if it retains diamagnetic property will that be same as before this process of conversion.
